# The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>' from Lint vs Pedantic

Tags: flutter, dart

I've just switched my linter in VSCode from Pedantic to Lint, and half of my app lit up. Most of it is easy to fix except for a string of Type assignment errors.  The following code taken mostly from examples gives the following error:

"The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'".

```
static List<Treatment> decodeData(String treatments) =>
      (jsonDecode(treatments) as List<dynamic>)
          .map<Treatment>((item) => Treatment.fromJson(item))
          .toList();
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Show your _ .fromJson method. I copied and replaced it with my code and it doesn't give any warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()`, like so:

```
  static List<Treatment> decodeData(String treatments) =>
      (jsonDecode(treatments) as List<dynamic>)
          .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
          .map<Treatment>((item) => Treatment.fromJson(item))
          .toList();
```

Comment: @robr I'm glad it did. Kindly mark it as the correct answer if the issue is solved. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting it at the end

```
static List<Treatment> decodeData(String treatments) =>
      (jsonDecode(treatments) as List<dynamic>)
          .map<Treatment>((item) => Treatment.fromJson(item))
          .toList() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't remove the error, and gave another:  A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be returned from the method '_decode' because it has a return type of 'List<Treatment>'